# Google map marker disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an issue with my map marker.  When you load the map the first time, everything works fine.  However when the div is hidden and re-shown (and calling the same function map()), the map loads fine but the marker doesn't come up, even though the map is centered in the position where I truly am.

Here is a snippet of the map coding:

```
function map(){ 
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.54, 15.35);
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var mapOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: latlng,
panControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
overviewMapControl: false
};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);    
  switch (map_view_id) {
case "1" :  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
            break;
case "2" :  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
            break;
case "3" :  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
            break;
  } 

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){     
    updateMap();           
   }); 
  }


function updateMap() {
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
  map.setZoom(13);

  marker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/android_asset/www//graphics/car.png",
new google.maps.Size(96.0, 96.0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(48.0, 48.0)
 );

  markerShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/android_asset/www/graphics/car_shadow.png",
new google.maps.Size(145.0, 96.0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(48.0, 48.0)
 ); 

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

  if(!markerUserPosition){
// Create marker
markerUserPosition = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: point,
  map: map,
  icon: marker,
  shadow: markerShadow,
  draggable:false,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
  } else {
     // Move marker
      markerUserPosition.setPosition(point);        
  }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Is there a way to destroy a Google map completely?  Because on hide I can technically destroy the map completely and load it when required.

Comment: Are you calling again updateMap() during **show** function?

Comment: @sk8terboi87 No I am just calling map().  Wouldn't updateMap() be called automatically when the tiles are loaded? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it will be loaded automatically when tiles loaded, but, for hide/show, i think you're jquery/js to do that, right? so tiles loaded won't be triggered, thats my guess.

Comment: @sk8terboi87 yes I'm using jQuery.  What if I do updateMap() just at the end of the map() function?  that should work right?

Comment: @sk8terboi87 when I did an updateMap() at the bottom of map(), on first load I get the marker at the top left corner but the map doesn't load then

Comment: Yep! Add a code (with a guess)... it'll be great if you post your hide show function also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22231/discussion-between-sk8terboi87-and-user1809790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you `$("#target-map-block").show();`, you can just rebuild the map by

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$("#button-id-to-show").click(function() {
  $("#target-map-block").show();
  updateMap();
});
```

Comment: It annoys whn someone puts downvote without a valid reason or comment.